# What's the meaning of 'to take bullshit'?

Tags: meaning

> And I love you, I don't love nobody else, yeah
>
> Tell them they can take that bullshit elsewhere

Another phrase I cannot to understand. How I undestand he lets a media to tell about it in their papers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*They can take that [anything] elsewhere* means "I want them to go away and stop bothering me with whatever it is".

The expression is *take [something] to [somewhere]*; with an adverbial like *somewhere* or *elsewhere*, the "to" is not required, but this is still the meaning.

"Bullshit" is just an extra derogatory epithet for whatever it is.

Comment: *Don't take any shit.* means don't take their derogatory epithets to heart. *"Bullshit"* in this context refers to lies. *'take your lies elsewhere'*. If someone's *bullshitting you*, they're trying to con you.

Comment: Yes, but _Don't take any shit_ is a different expression, which is not at play here.

Comment: My point is that if you replace that "[anything]" with *bullshit*, more than just being derogatory, it often connotes insincerity. *take that shit elsewhere* speaks to the inappropriateness of the thing. *take that bullshit elsewhere* refers to the ineptitude of the giver (and their 'crap').

Comment: @Colin Fine, the best explanation for me, thank you!